# How to display image from drawable in imageview on map click?

Tags: android, xml

i have implemented google maps and have set a imageview on linear layout at the bottom of maps.
i m not understanding how to display an image from drawable in imageview on map click..
people helping with the suggestion ,
Thanks in advance..

Comment: you can capture onMapClick event in java code and then change image

Comment: Yeah..I have  set the on map click event..but i am not understanding the logic of how to call the imageview on map click

Comment: i have implemented on map click evbent in my code.

Comment: Initially set visibility of ImageView to GONE.. then change visibility to VISIBLE when onClick of map is enabled.

Comment: yes this is what i thought of doing but that come in xml coding.I am not understanding what logic can be used to call image in imageview on map click event..

Comment: you can setVisibility wiht java code also

Comment: No no u can do it by dynamic way.

Comment: Can you post your code, what you have tried earlier..?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener();
```

and on in onCLick() you can set

```
ImageView.setImageResource();
```

For more info you can read [Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/events)

Comment: if (latLng != null) {
     imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
      imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      String uri = "@drawable/choppers";  // where myresource.png is the file
      // extension removed from the String

      int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());

      Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
      imageView.setImageDrawable(res);

    }

Comment: public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
       if(googleMap!=null){
           googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);

             
 }

Comment: Is the above logic i tried implementing right?because basically on click imageview is disappearing

Comment: You want to show image on Click or you want to hide Image on CLick?

Comment: No, The above logic is wrong, you want on image to display on CLikc

Comment: androgo u were right, the logic that i implemented was completly opp to what i wanted to achieve.Anyways thanks.i achieved what i wanted.Now i actually wnt to call the array of images on different latlong ranges.

Answer (score 0):

you can set ImageView image from drawable folder as

```
yourImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourImage);
```

Comment: it show an error : non static setImageResource() cannot be reffered from static context

Comment: LatLng[] polygonLatLngs = {
            new LatLng(37.784, -122.405),
            new LatLng(37.784, -122.406),
            new LatLng(37.785, -122.406),
            new LatLng(37.785, -122.405)
    };
    map.addPolygon(new AirMapPolygon.Builder().add(polygonLatLngs).strokeWidth(3.f).build());

    // Add Circle
    map.drawCircle(new LatLng(37.78443, -122.40805), 1000);

    // enable my location
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);